# Add class to link on scroll plus add same class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i need a little bit of help with this page: http://www.levelidiomes.com/new/ (on the part called Formaciò) i have this js

http://www.levelidiomes.com/new/wp-content/themes/Kronos-WP2/js/formacio.js

That is adding a class to the menu on the left (called nav.stickymeny) also is doing other stuff for this specific part.

So, i need to:

1. add the active class when scrolling over the section
2. add the active class to the clicked link

I don't know why is not working correctly please helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the .js is fine.  It's adding the 'active' class when it's supposed to.

adding this little bit of CSS worked for me:

`.stickymeny .active {
color: #whatever;
}`

Comment: Dude i feel so stupid i totally erase that bit of css by mistake and didn´t noticed it. thanks a bunch!